# JavaScript: Convert object structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this:

```
{
  "A": [ "-4927","8779","-9971","-23767" ],
  "B": [ "-10617","-1456","3131","259" ],
  "C": [ "-5185","1168","21501","18989" ],
  "D": [ "2010","5664","2148","-674" ]
}
```

I want to convert to this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'A',
    data: ["-4927","8779","-9971","-23767"]
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    data: ["-10617","-1456","3131","259"]
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    data: ["-5185","1168","21501","18989"]
  }, {
    name: 'D',
    data: ["2010","5664","2148","-674"]
  }
]
```

I have used this following method:

```
var newData = [];
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(k, v) {
  newData['name'] = k;
  newData['data'] = v;
});
```

But it only store the last key pair value as newData. That is

```
name: 'D',
data: ["2010","5664","2148","-674"]
```

I understand that it overwrite the previous data and store only the last data it get. But i can't solve this problem.

Any Help ?

Comment: Use another array to store the json array.

Comment: Your overlaying the name and data field on the newData, rather than creating a new sub object and putting it in the array, with those fields

Comment: Side note, any time you see a block of code that effectively does `#1) create array, #2) loop over another element, #3) push elements to created array`, this is the pattern that you should consider using either `$.fn.map` or `$.map`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are assigning the properties `name` and `data` directly to `newData` instead of pushing an object into it as an array:

Change your loop to this:

```
var newData = [];
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(k, v) {
        const myNewData = {
            name: k,
            data: v
        }
        newData.push(myNewData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It Works :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using `map`

```js
const oldData =
  { "A": [ "-4927","8779","-9971","-23767" ]
  , "B": [ "-10617","-1456","3131","259" ]
  , "C": [ "-5185","1168","21501","18989" ]
  , "D": [ "2010","5664","2148","-674" ]
  }

const newShape = ([ name, data ]) =>
  ({ name, data })

const newData =
  Object.entries(oldData).map(newShape)

console.log(newData)
// [ { name: "A", data: [ "-4927","8779","-9971","-23767" ] }, ... ]
```

You can write the lambda inline, if you wish, but it's generally better to write programs with reusable pieces

```
const newData =
  Object.entries(oldData).map(([ name, data ]) => ({ name, data }))
```

jQuery can map over objects using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) – note the differing lambda

```
const newData =
  $.map(oldData, (data, name) => ({ name, data }))
```

Comment: Like it with destructuration, well thought. Be carefull tho about the support of the `Object.entries` method in browser [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries)

Answer (score 4):

You can use of `Object.keys` and `Array.map` to generate your array.

It can be translated to this:

> for each key in my object data, create a new item inside of a new
>   array. This item is going to be an object, with a key name and a key data.

---

```js
const data = {
  A: ['-4927', '8779', '-9971', '-23767'],
  B: ['-10617', '-1456', '3131', '259'],
  C: ['-5185', '1168', '21501', '18989'],
  D: ['2010', '5664', '2148', '-674'],
};

const ret = Object.keys(data).map(x => ({
  name: x,
  data: data[x],
}));

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `for in` loop and `push` each element.

```js
var obj = {
    "A":["-4927","8779","-9971","-23767"],
    "B":["-10617","-1456","3131","259"],
    "C":["-5185","1168","21501","18989"],
    "D":["2010","5664","2148","-674"]
  }

var newArr = [];

  for(p in obj){
    newArr.push({"name":p,"data":obj[p]})
  }

  console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
var newData = [];
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(k, v) {
    newData.push({'name': k, 'data': v});
});
```

You also don't need to use jQuery. You can do the same in vanilla JS:

```
var newData = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {
    newData.push({'name': k, 'data': data[k]});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return your expected result.

```
var newData = [];
for(var key in data) {
    newData.push({
        name: key,
        data: data[key]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we weren't using `jQuery`, we could use a combination of [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

`Object.keys(data)` would simply return `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

---

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

In that map function callback we can return an object in the specific way we need our data formatted.

```js
const data = {
  "A": ["-4927", "8779", "-9971", "-23767"],
  "B": ["-10617", "-1456", "3131", "259"],
  "C": ["-5185", "1168", "21501", "18989"],
  "D": ["2010", "5664", "2148", "-674"]
}

const newData = Object.keys(data).map(function(prop) {
  return {
    name: prop,
    data: data[prop]
  }
})

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea :)